# org.apache.ibatis.builder.IncompleteElementException: Could not find result map . Why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis

I cannot map the result of a query to a bean with MyBatis and Spring Boot using an xml file.

Configuration: spring boot, mybatis.

1) I have a Mapper:

```
package ru.kq.cn.mapper;

@Mapper
public interface GateMapper {



    @Select("call [dbo].[cai_Select] 1, ")
    @ResultMap("GateMapper.WResultMap")
    WQueryResult call();
}
```

2) At the same package I have xml for ResultSet:

```
 <mapper namespace="ru.kq.cn.mapper.GateMapper">
    <resultMap id="WResultMap" type="ru.kq.cn.dto.WQueryResult">
        <result property="proverTpId" column="proverTpId"/>
        <collection property="itemIds" column="itemId">
        </collection>
    </resultMap>
 </mapper>
```

3) DTO:

```
package ru.kq.cn.dto;
 ..

@Data

public class WQueryResult implements Serializable {
    Long proverTpId;
    List <String>  itemIds;
}
```

3) application.properties:

```
mybatis.type-aliases-package=ru.kq.cn.dto
mybatis.mapper-locations='classpath:ru/kq/cn/mapper/*.xml'
```

4) App:

```
 @MapperScan("ru.kq.cn.mapper")
@SpringBootApplication
public class  Application   {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
 }
```

Please help!

Comment: Can you update the question with the database procedure code as well?

Comment: `@ResultMap("GateMapper.WResultMap")` is wrong. It should be either `@ResultMap("WResultMap")` or `@ResultMap("ru.kq.cn.mapper.GateMapper.WResultMap")`.

Comment: @ave did not help

Comment: @Smile the procedure return multiple result list. one result returns 1 row with proverTpId and another result returns 5 rows with itemId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't mention, I assumed that the DB is MS SQL Server.

A few basics.

- To call a stored procedure, you need to set `statementType="CALLABLE"`.
- In JDBC, the syntax to call stored procedure is `{call proc(?,?,...)}`.
- To handle multiple result sets, you need to name each result set using `resultSets` of the statement.

So, the mapper method may look something like this:

```java
@Select("{call [dbo].[cai_Select](1)}")
@ResultMap("WResultMap")
@Options(
    statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE,
    resultSets = "firstRS,secondRS">
WQueryResult call();
```

Your procedure returns two result sets. I named them `firstRS` and `secondRS` respectively.

And in the result map, specify the  `resultSet` attribute of `<collection />`.
I assumed that the second result set is for the `itemIds`.

```xml
<resultMap id="WResultMap" type="ru.kq.cn.dto.WQueryResult">
  <result property="proverTpId" column="proverTpId"/>
  <collection property="itemIds" ofType="java.lang.String"
      javaType="java.util.ArrayList" resultSet="secondRS">
    <id column="itemId">
  </collection>
</resultMap>
```

Mapping to `List<String>` is a little bit tricky. We have an [FAQ entry](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-map-a-list-of-simple-type-objects-string-integer-etc-to-a-bean-or-map-).

Here is an executable [demo project](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-59543132).
To demonstrate mapping of parent-child relationships, it is more complicated than yours.